# Removing one-one and one-many references - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an `Assignment schema` which has references to `Groups` and `Projects`.

```
Assignment == Group [One-One Relationship]
Assignment == Projects [One-Many Relationship]
```

Below is my `Asssignment` Schema

```
var AssignmentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    group: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Group'
    },
    projects: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project'}],
});
```

If a `Group/Project` is removed, how can i update my Assignment Schema.

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

From couple of answers in stackoverflow, i came to know about the remove middleware, but i am not sure how to implement it for `one-one and one-many` relationship. Can anyone show me an example of doing it.

```
ProjectSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
    this.model('Assignment').update(

    );
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Relationships:**

1. A `one-to-one is a relationship` such that a state has only one
   capital city and a capital city is the capital of only one state
2. A `one-to-many is a relationship` such that a mother has many
   children, and the children have only one mother
3. A `many-to-many is a relationship` such that a book can be written by
   several authors or co-authors, while an author can write several
   books.

one-one relationship - **If a `Project/Group` is removed, how can i update my `Assignment` Schema.**

Typically you will have one `project` mapped to one `assignment` and similarly one `assignment` mapped to one `project`. what you can do here is removing a project and then find the associated `project` in assignment model and remove their references.

```
delete: function(req, res) {
   return Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, project){
         return project.remove(function(err){
             if(!err) {
                 Assignment.update({_id: project.assignment}}, 
                      {$pull: {projects: project._id}}, 
                          function (err, numberAffected) {
                            console.log(numberAffected);
                      } else {
                        console.log(err);                                      
                    }
                  });
            });
        });
}
```

one-many relationship - **If a `Project/Group` is removed, how can i update my `Assignment` Schema.**

In this scenario we are removing a project and then finding all the `assignments` which belongs to this `project` and removing its reference from them. Here the situation is, there can be many assignments for a single project.

```
delete: function(req, res) {
   return Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, project){
         return project.remove(function(err){
             if(!err) {
                 Assignment.update({_id: {$in: project.assingments}}, 
                      {$pull: {project: project._id}}, 
                           function (err, numberAffected) {
                            console.log(numberAffected);
                      } else {
                        console.log(err);                                      
                    }
                  });
            });
        });
}
```

**Remove middleware**

You could achieve the same thing via `middleware` as pointed out by Johnny, just a correction on that..

```
ProjectSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    var project = this;
    project.model('Assignment').update(
        { projects: {$in: project.assignments}}, 
        { $pull: { project: project._id } }, 
        { multi: true }, 
        next
     );
});
```

Typically there can be many `projects` belonging to an `assignment` and many `assignments` belonging to the same `project`. You will have an `assignment` column in your `Project` Schema where one project will relate to multiple assignments.

**Note:** remove middleware won't work on models and it would only work on your documents. If you are going with `remove` middleware ensure in your delete function, you find `project` by id first and then on the returned `document` apply the remove method, so for the above to work... your delete function would look like this.

```
delete: function(req, res) {
   return Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, project){
         return project.remove(function(err){
             if(!err) {
                  console.log(numberAffected);
             } 
           });                
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

In the `remove` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), you're defining the actions to take when a document of the model for that schema is removed via [`Model#remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove).  So:

- When a group is removed, you want to remove the `group` reference to that group's `_id` from all assignment docs.
- When a project is removed, you want to remove the `projects` array element references to that project's `_id` from all assignment docs.

Which you can implement as:

```
GroupSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    var group = this;
    group.model('Assignment').update(
        { group: group._id }, 
        { $unset: { group: 1 } }, 
        { multi: true },
        next);
});

ProjectSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    var project = this;
    project.model('Assignment').update(
        { projects: project._id }, 
        { $pull: { projects: project._id } }, 
        { multi: true }, 
        next);
});
```