# how to delete document from collection in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have id printing in controller from client  now i want to delete this document from mongodb with below code is not showing any error but not even deleting document from collection , How can i delete document using `_id` ?

controller.js

```
var Diagram = {
    remove: function(id, res) {
        console.log('deletecontroller', id);
        diagram.remove({
            _id: id
        });
    }
}
module.exports = Diagram;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether `diagram` is your model here, try with your Model, because i don't see you are getting a document via `find or findOne` method on which you can apply `remove` method.

```
Model.remove({ _id: id}, function(err){});
```

Or you can also find and remove:

```
Model.findOne({_id: id}, function (error, daigram){
   daigram.remove();
});
```

You can also use the latest version:

```
MyModel.findOneAndRemove({_id: id}, function(err){...});
```

Comment: Thanks alot first one worked for me just to understand why callback is required to delete a document.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove, you require two params... and more over you need to a callback so that nodejs can inform you when it has removed your document... in your callback and pas on to its next operation...

Comment: @hussain: Did it help?

Comment: Thanks for explanation it definitely helped to understand callback.

Comment: This link will also help you in understanding when you want to remove references... one to one, one to many and many to many... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674280/removing-one-one-and-one-many-references-mongoose/32751150#32751150

Comment: Do you think this is good approach to remove document in terms of asycn calls.

Comment: @hussain: yes, it should have no problems.. if you have a series of async calls happening... look at async library... like async.series, async.parallel

Comment: Also look at the remove middle in the answer i have given there, it would help in you some corner cases.