# mongodb pull/delete not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I have some issue with deleting the object in array
the result of that API always "modification deleted"
in case the "iduser" invalid or valid
and the object not deleted in Modification doc and Account doc

this is my main doc

```
let Account = new Schema({
  firstName       : {type : String, required : true},
  lastName        : String,
  email           : {type : String, required : true},
  profilePicture  : {type : String, required : true},
  gender          : {type : String, required : true},
  id              : {type : String, required : true},
  location        : String,
  birthday        : Date,
  experiences     : [Number],
  achievements    : [Number],
  modifications   : {type : [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref : 'Modification'}
},{usePushEach: true});
```

and this the array object i wanna delete

```
let modificationSchema = new Schema({
  desc      : {type : String, required : true},
  make      : {type : String, required : true},
  type      : {type : String, required : true},
  photo     : {type : String, required : true},
  postDate  : {type : Date,   required : true},
  likes     : {type : [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref : 'Like'},
  comments  : {type : [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref : 'Comment'}
},{usePushEach: true});
```

and this my code for deleting modification object from Account object

```
api.put('/modification/:iduser/:idmodif' , (req,res) =>{
    Account.findOneAndUpdate({"email":req.params.iduser},
      { $pull : { modifications : { _id : req.params.idmodif}}}, 
function(err,model){
        if(err){
          return res.send(err);
        }else{
          res.json({message : "modification deleted"});
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing one-one and one-many references - Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674280/removing-one-one-and-one-many-references-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard technique

```
api.put('/modification/:iduser/:idmodif' , (req,res) =>{
    Account.findById({_id:req.params.iduser}, 
function(err,model){
        model.modifications = null;
        model.save(function(err,result){
        if(err){
          return res.send(err);
        }else{
          res.json({message : "modification deleted"});
        }
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but that technique just delete the reference object in "Account.modification" only (_id) . and the real object in "Modification doc" still exist. just look my schema.