# How do I also delete the ObjectId from the parent element with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So essentially what I have is a location index. Here is the location schema:

```
    var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    gps: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    catches: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Catch"
        }
        ]
});
```

In this schema I also have "catches" essentially just a comment. Here is the schema for that:

```
var catchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    species: String,
    weight: String,
    image: String,
    catchlocation: String,
    description: String,
    timePosted: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
},
   {timestamps: true}
);
```

I allow a user to delete a "catch" (or comment) with this route:

```
app.delete("/locations/:id/catch/:catchid", isUserPost, function(req, res){
    Catch.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.catchid, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            req.flash("success", "Your catch has been deleted.");
            res.redirect("/locations/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Now to the problem, when the "catch" (aka comment) is deleted, it is deleted from the "catches" collection, BUT the ObjectId remains in the location. With mongoose, how would I also delete the catch ObjectId from the parent element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing one-one and one-many references - Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674280/removing-one-one-and-one-many-references-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it manually. My sugestion is to do it using Mongoose middleware, with pre-remove hook:

```
catchSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    // you can use 'this' to extract the _id   this._id and find it in locations documents and remove where it appears
    /** do the thing **/
    next();
});
```

Comment: Didn't even know that existed. Thanks for the help.