# MongoDB many to many relationships

Tags: javascript, sql, database, mongodb

Im new to mongodb (come from SQL) and was wondering how do I handle many-to-many relationships. Say I have a schema User and a schema Event. The user schema will have a field called 'events' which is a list of events they are attending. The Event schema will have a field 'users' which contains the users attending events.
I was told the standard way is to do the following:

```
var UserSchema= new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    events: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Event'} ]
});

var EventSchema= new Schema({
    id: ObjectId,
    users: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'} ]
});
```

However, what if I want to remove a user from an event? I will have to modify both schemas, whereas in standard SQL I could have a seperate Schema called UserEvents which contains a field for the user ID and event ID. what is best practice for something like this?

Comment: yea you need to modify both. thats an weak point at noSQL, you dont have relations

Comment: Yes, you have to modify both schemas. A common way to do so is by using a [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) an example can be found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32718833/3257622)